# $\int \int_{C} \phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy \geq \int \int_{S} \phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy$

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function

Let $C$ be a circle of unit area with centre at
origin and let $S$ be a square of unit area with $(1/2,1/2)$,$(-1/2,1/2)$,$(1/2,-1/2)$ and $(-1/2,-1/2)$
as the four vertices. If $X$ and $Y$ be two independent standard normal variate, show
that
$$\int \int_{C} \phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy \geq \int \int_{S} \phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy$$ where $\phi()$ is the pdf of $N(0,1)$

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: **HINT:** Take e.g $\phi(s)=e^{-s^2}$. Convert to polar coordinates. Note that the function $(r,\theta)\mapsto \phi(r\cos\theta)\phi(r\sin\theta)=\phi(r)$ is decreasing. Now compute the average distance of a point in $C$ and a point in $S$ from the origin.